# Script for moving files that are older than 5 days

Tags: bash, scripts, files, directory, mv

I'm currently working on a script that allows me to move any file thats older than 5 days into an archive folder with the same path, except for the root folder which changes.
So something like:
`root/subdir1/subdir2/file` to `rootarchive/subdir1/subdir2/file`.
It should work recursivly.

I've already tried creating a foreach for all the files of the "root" folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      mv $file ../rootarchive/"$file"
done
```

But this didn't work properly as I the mv command couldnt find the specified destination `../rootarchive/"$file"`.
Has anyone of you an idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: What about using absolute paths instead of relative ones? For instance: /tmp/rootarchive/"$file" Regards

Comment: The kernel doesn't support providing informations about the creation time of a file, so if you need to move files older than X you'll have to work out a way to to do the check using `debugfs`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create the directory tree from `subdir1/subdir2/` - `mv` won't do that for you. You could do, for example:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    dir="${file%/*}"
    mkdir -p ../rootarchive/"$dir"
    mv "$file" ../rootarchive/"$file"
done
```

---

You could `rsync`. It can recreate the directory structure and do deleting copied files:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -print0 | 
  rsync -0avP  --remove-source-files --files-from=- ./ ../rootarchive
```

For `rsync`:

- `-0` indicates file lists are null-separated. This affects:
- `--files-from=` reads the list of files to be copied (from stdin: `-`).
- `-a` enables archive mode, which retains file permissions, ownership, etc.
- `--remove-source-files` deletes files which have been copied *successfully* from the source.
- `-vP` enable verbose mode and progress information.

Comment: Thx for your help worked perfectly fine!